# Why the usercontrol size is changing each time i'm dragging the control over form1 designer?

Tags: c#, winforms

once I dragged the usercontrol to form1 designer.
then I tried to change the usercontrol size while it's on form1 designer but then when I drag the usercontrol around the usercontrol size is changing.

here are two screenshots showing the usercontrol size each time I'm dragging it.

the usercontrol is the map.

when I hold down the mouse on the usercontrol it's in its actual size:

[image: user control is the map]

once I leave the mouse left button and not holding it down the size of the usercontrol has changed on the usercontrol designer I can see the usercontrol actual size but most of is empty the map inside is now smaller:

[image: usercontrol the map inside google map size has changed the usercontrol size not changed as I can see but the map inside size has changed.]

the user control code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DotNetBrowser.Browser;
using DotNetBrowser.Engine;
using DotNetBrowser.WinForms;

namespace Weather
{
    public partial class GoogleMapsUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public static IBrowser browser;
        public static IEngine engine;

        public GoogleMapsUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            engine = EngineFactory.Create(new EngineOptions.Builder
            {
                LicenseKey = "KEY HERE"
            }.Build());

            // Create and initialize the IEngine
            //engine = EngineFactory.Create();

            // Create the Windows Forms BrowserView control
            BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };

            // Create the IBrowser
            browser = engine.CreateBrowser();
            browser.Navigation.LoadProgressChanged += Navigation_LoadProgressChanged;
            browser.Navigation.LoadFinished += Navigation_LoadFinished;
            browser.Navigation.LoadUrl("D:\\Csharp Projects\\Weather\\map.html");

            // Initialize the Windows Forms BrowserView control
            browserView.InitializeFrom(browser);

            this.Controls.Add(browserView);

            
        }

        private void Navigation_LoadProgressChanged(object sender, DotNetBrowser.Navigation.Events.LoadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Navigation_LoadFinished(object sender, DotNetBrowser.Navigation.Events.LoadFinishedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void GoogleMapsUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have dragged the map usercontrol INSIDE the GroupBox "Download", so the map is "clipped" by the groupbox limits. Drag the map control outside the groupbox, directly over the form.

Example of ListView inside GroupBox:

[image]